# Firebase и генерация ссылок на превью видео

Tags: ios, firebase

Умеет ли Firebase генерировать ссылки на превью видео,которые храниятся в базе данных?

Comment: [гляньте тут](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/)

Comment: Спасибо,но это не то что надо. Я думаю Firebase не умеет генерировать ссылки.